# How to use stylesheets from a referenced node module

Tags: css, npm, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a VS Code module. It uses `highlight.js` to generate HTML for syntax highlighting of source code. The `highlight.js` npm module contains a folder `styles` which is full of CSS files I would like to use.

What do I have to do so that I can access these CSS files at run-time?

I mean *all of them*.

I suspect something like `require` will be needed to cause them to be bundled in the absence of an explicit reference to each CSS file, but I need guidance on how to do this.

Also how does one access the bundled resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do anything. Bundling happens automatically. Your project's `node_modules` folder accompanies the extension when it is deployed.

To access resources within these modules you need to know where they are. The answer to that is they are deployed to a `node_modules` folder located directly on the extension path.

So how do you determine the location of the extension folder at run-time? You could use the method described by [VSCode extensions location variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51670505) but I don't recommend it. Instead, do it like this:

```
let x = vscode.extensions.getExtension("dilcorp.groovyext");
if (!x) {
  throw new Error("Cannot resolve extension. Has the name changed? " +
                  "It is defined by the publisher and the extension name " + 
                  "which are defined in package.json`); 
}
let stylePath = `${x.extensionPath}/node_modules/highlight.js/styles`;
```

There are two parts to the above code. First we get runtime information about the extension, which includes its absolute file path as a property `extensionPath`.

The second part exploits the fact that our extension project's node_modules is copied into the extensionPath folder.

This works in the debugger.