# VS Code Extension Not Including Folders on Compile

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to make the extension I'm developing include files from a folder that contains SVG images in my extension's `/out` folder, but only js and js.map files are being generated.

The project structure is as follows:

```
--ProjectRoot
----out
----resources
------dark
------light
----src
------menus
------service
----extension.ts
----package.json
----tsconfig.json
```

TS config:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "out",
        "lib": [
            "es6"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": false,
        "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        ".vscode-test",
        "test"
    ]
}
```

Launch config:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
            "name": "Run Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": [
                "--disable-extensions",
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: watch"
        },
        {
            "name": "Extension Tests",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}",
                "--extensionTestsPath=${workspaceFolder}/out/test"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/test/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: watch"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried changing `rootDir` in the TS config and various blob patterns for `outFiles` in the launch config, but still cannot seem to get the extension to include the `resources` folder and it's children.

This is causing part of my extension to get net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND messages when looking for icons.

Can someone provider any pointers on the right way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need the resources to be copied to `out` to begin with.

Comment: @Gama11 I just need a reference-able place to put my SVG and other image files so I can make sure icons load properly when debugging

Comment: The project root should be fine for that though. Maybe you're looking for `ExtensionContext.asAbsolutePath()`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51670505/vscode-extensions-location-variable/51679267#51679267

Comment: @Gama11 thanks for that, your tips are always helpful

Comment: Easy fix seemed to be to just package my extension and install it, and accessing the icons through %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions\myextensionname\resources

Comment: That's not going to work consistently, for instance on non-Windows or for marketplace releases where the folder name contains the version number. Have you tried `asAbsolutePath()`?

Comment: @Gama11 no but intend to take a look at it. In this case my audience is internal to my company, so in my situation this'll work but yea `asAbsolutePath()` seems like a solid way to go for more general uses. Thanks again for the pro tip