# How to inject variables in separated html file when developing vscode extension

Tags: html, typescript, vscode-extensions, string-interpolation

I am developing a vscode extension.
I'm really uncomfortable with having the html in a string (example: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/webview-view-sample/src/extension.ts). This makes the file huge plus there is no intelisense in the html part.

I have found this article that helped me to retrieve the html from an html file: [Use HTML files in Visual Studio Code extension development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236058/use-html-files-in-visual-studio-code-extension-development)

My code:

```
const quickviewHtml = fs.readFileSync(
      vscode.Uri.joinPath(
        this._extensionUri,
        "src",
        "providers",
        "quickview",
        "quick-view.html"
      ).fsPath,
      "utf8"
    );
```

But now I have a problem, and that is that I can't use interpolation. For example:

```
<h1>Hi ${name}</h1>
```

This is because the retrieved string is single quoted instead of back quoted.

How can I use interpolation?
Is there a cleaner way to separate the html from the typescript file and still have the ability to use interpolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example can be that you use a templating engine, [ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) is an example. If you only need to insert a handful of variables. You can do it yourself by using [`String.prototype.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll). An example

```js
const quickviewHtml = fs.readFileSync(
      vscode.Uri.joinPath(
        this._extensionUri,
        "src",
        "providers",
        "quickview",
        "quick-view.html"
      ).fsPath,
      "utf8"
    )
    .toString()
    .replaceAll('{{name}}', name);
```

now you can replace in your html file `${name}` to `{{name}}` and and the result string should be what you expect.

Comment: I was thinking of using something like what you propose. But the truth is that it seems to me a little clean solution. I guess if I want something more professional, I'll have to use something like Svelte or React. Thank you so much.